# How can I get my table to display above my ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms

I am trying to create a menu in the MasterPage that is displayed when a hyperlink is clicked. YardimDokumaniMenuAHREF is the hyperlink that displays the menu. As you can see, a javascript is called when I click on it. However contensts of the cells can not be displayed due to contentplaceholder. Please see the [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38860715/screenshot.png).

and this is my code. can someone help me out with this?

```
<a id="YardimDokumaniMenuAHREF" href="javascript:DisplayMenu('ctl00_YardimDokumaniMenuContent')" runat="server" title="">YARDIM DÖKÜMANI</a>
<%-- YardimDokumaniMenuAHREF triggers YardimDokumaniMenuContent to be displayed --%>

<div ID="YardimDokumaniMenuContent" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; z-index:-99999">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/YardimDokumanlari/YeniSayfa?key=38fad920-196c-48d9-a2fa-3df052c0cb0c">hadi bakalııııım</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/YardimDokumanlari/YeniSayfa?key=38fad920-196c-48d9-a2fa-3df052c0cb0c">hadi bakalııııım333</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="~/Default.aspx" title="Ana Sayfa" runat="server" id="AnaSayfaLink">
                        Ana Sayfa</a> </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="~/Everyone/iletisim.aspx" runat="server" title="Bilgi almak istiyorum, şikayetim var, haklı müşteriyim.">
                        İLETİŞİM / YARDIM MASASI</a></li>
                    <li class="current_page_item" runat="server" id="OnlineIslemLink"><a id="A1" runat="server"
                        href="https://ode.a-kent.com/Yetki/Login.aspx">ONLINE İŞLEM</a> </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LogoutLinkButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="LogoutLinkButton_Click">GÜVENLİ ÇIKIŞ</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- globalNav end -->
        </div>
        <!-- header end -->
        <div id="main">
            <div class="panel fetaured" style="left: 192px; top: 0px; width: 755px;">
                <div class="comments">
                    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);"><b>GERİ</b></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LeftPanelContentPlaceHolder">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Display menu function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayMenu(obj) {
        obj = document.getElementById(obj);
        obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "due contentplaceholder". What that has to do with anything?

Comment: hello @ivowiblo, sorry about my language. if you saw the screenshot, contents of the table (cells) stays under contentplaceholder. thats what I meant. Please feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: I don't see any contentplaceholder in the code...

Comment: Could you put it on the sample code you have provided?

Comment: Ok. It seems the some part of the html are missing. Could you also post the function "DisplayMenu"?

Comment: Ok. Few thoughts: what happens if the text of the YardimDokumaniMenuContent are red? I want to know if the content is being displayed but confused with the background, or if it's being hidden behind what you put in the placeholder.

Comment: i don't understand what this has to do with the text color? I typed those red texts on ms paint and drew the red circle with also ms paint just to show that what part of the page I am talking about.

it is just being hidden behind whatever contentplaceholder has.

Comment: I mean, the text color and the background are the same (both are grey). So I don't know if it's being rendered well but you cannot see it because of the colors, or if it is being rendered behind the contents.

Comment: I made the text green just to check it. dl.dropbox.com/u/38860715/screenshot2.png and it is just being rendered behind the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `z-index:-99999`from the YardimDokumaniMenuContent div style. If that doesn't work, ensure the z-index of that div is greater than the one of the background.

Comment: i tried to give z-index to every single div to order them properly but divs just don't listen what I say. they just hang out there all by themselves :(

Comment: Why did you put z-index:-99999 in the first place?

Comment: The problem, I think, is that you are putting the <div> inside the <li> and the <li> has a fixed height. If you want to put a div ouside the list items (ul), then place the <div> outside it.

Comment: z-index had to simply work, but asp and I just don't speak the same language I guess. well, I came here to tell you and the people who may encounter same obstacle one day that z-index works but my master page is so messed up that z-index just couldnt do much so we took another way to achieve it. 

I thank you very much and thank you for your time.